# How does PyUnit handle temporary files?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing a directory backup script in Python 2.7, and using the opportunity to learn about unit testing in the language.  I am at the point now where the script can create the backup directory and fill it with copies of the files I want in there.  I think...

I have a unit test that creates the backup and then calls

```
self.failUnless("scan0002.pdf" in os.listdir("C:\\backuptest\\My Scans"))
```

where scan0002 is a file that should have been copied.  The test passes... but the directory in question has not actually been created.  Even weirder, I can

```
print os.listdir("C:\\backuptest\\My Scans")
```

and get a list of filenames that are supposedly in that directory during the test, but again, the directory does not actually exist.

So I am guessing that PyUnit has something built in to allow it to test functionality without actually changing the file system, but I cannot find any documentation on it.  How does this work, and probably more importantly, does this lead to better practices for testing this kind of script other than writing the tests based on my local machine configuration?

Comment: AFAIK the `unittest` module does *not* mock file-creation etc. functionalities, which means that the directory `"C:\\backuptest\\My Scans"` exists on your machine and during the test your code is actually performing the file copy for real. How are you checking whether it exists or not? Anyway for this kind of things you should either mock the built-ins and simply check whether the program would do the right calls, or you should use the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to create a temporary directory where you can do the tests.

Comment: I looked for the directory by navigating to the C: directory and seeing that it wasn't there, refreshing it a bunch of times, and then using the windows search feature to look for both it and a couple of the files that were supposedly in there.  I didn't believe it either and spent a pretty good amount of time verifying that it didn't exist...